# angular.js: routing to an editor-version of the current article

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some articles of the same category and I'm routing like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/chapter/:title', {
        templateUrl: 'article.html',
        controller: 'article'
    });
});
```

**article.html:**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>{{content}}</p>
<button>Editor</button>
```

But now I want to get a route from every article of this chapter to an editor version to change the content. This editor-version could look like this:

**editor_article.html:**

```
<input type="text" value="{{title}}">
<textarea>{{content}}</textarea>
```

So what is the best way for routing the button of an article to the editor_article.html-template and load it with the same data?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "best-way" here, and it all depends on your context.

Do all end-users have equal access to this (or put another way, should anybody who can open the dev-console be allowed to access this page)?

If not, you need to solve the login problem *before* you load most of the code for your SPA.

If login isn't a problem, or already taken care of, why do you need separate routes?
Do you need to cache these pages separately in-browser?
Are there other considerations beyond that?
Totally legitimate question; from an artistic perspective, perhaps you're hoping for page transitions which match other transitions you have for when you *do* change routes, or you are relying on routeParams for some logic that we don't know about.

But chances are good that all of the above things aside, you could simply have a button and a couple of ng-if statements, with directives.

```
<body >
    <main ng-view></main>
</body>

<!-- template -->
<section >
    <button
        ng-click="article.toggleMode()">{{
          article.editMode ? "View": "Edit"
    }}</button>
    <article-view
        content="article.content"
        ng-if="!article.editMode"
    ></article-view>
    <article-edit
        content="article.content"
        onsave="article.save(content)"
        ng-if="article.editMode"
    ></article-edit>
</section>
```

Using directives to define the two templates, using `controllerAs:"article"` in the example above.

Even that might be complicating it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, only "logged-in" user have the permission to change articles. But I didn't realized the login so far, as I didn't find a good authentication-method.